# NHibernate child collection Projection to DTO

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I have had a good look around for answers on this, and several questions suggest this cannot be done.

[Nhibernate projection with child collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154280/nhibernate-projection-with-child-collection)

[NHibernate QueryOver projections - projecting collections to DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535961/nhibernate-queryover-projections-projecting-collections-to-dto)

[NHibernate Projections - how to project collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563804/nhibernate-projections-how-to-project-collections)

So I was wondering what would be a good work around to project a child collection to my DTO.
Will I need to run two seperate projections and manually add the children to the parent?

I am using NH 3.3.1 I have the following DTO data structure

```
 public class ProviderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<EmployerDTO> Employers { get; set; }
}


 public class EmployerDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I would like to map my Provider and employer domain entities to this structure with a projection. (In this simple scenario my domain entities are very similar to my dto's)

```
Employer employerAlias = null;
Provider providerAlias = null;
ProviderDto providerDto = null;

var dto = session.QueryOver<Provider>(() => providerAlias)
            .JoinAlias(x => x.Employers, () => employerAlias)
            .Where(()=> providerAlias.Id == 1)
            .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
            .Add(Projections.Property(() => providerAlias.Id).WithAlias(() => providerDto.Id))
            .Add(Projections.Property(() => providerAlias.Name).WithAlias(() => providerDto.Name))

              //This is where I cannot project my child employer collection
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ProviderDto>()).List<ProviderDto>();
```

How could I map across the child collection? 
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should batch queries using futures and construct the relationship yourself.

```
Employer employerAlias = null;
Provider providerAlias = null;
ProviderDto providerDto = null;
EmployerDto employerDto = null;

var providers = session.QueryOver<Provider>(() => providerAlias)
        .JoinAlias(x => x.Employers, () => employerAlias)
        .Where(()=> providerAlias.Id == 1)
        .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => providerAlias.Id).WithAlias(() =>    providerDto.Id))
        .Add(Projections.Property(() => providerAlias.Name).WithAlias(() => providerDto.Name))
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ProviderDto>()).Future<ProviderDto>();

var employers = session.QueryOver<Employer>(() => employerAlias)
//Etc 
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<EmployerDto>()).Future<EmployerDto>();
```

Then it's a matter of mapping the correct employers to providers. You might need more information in the DTO for that, but using Future queries, you will only make one database roundtrip to get all the information.

EDIT:

In order to get which employers map to which providers.

```
session.QueryOver(() => provider)
       .JoinAlias(() => provider.Employers, () => employer)
       .SelectList(list => list.Select(() => provider.Id).WithAlias(() =>     peDTO.ProviderId)
                               .Select(() => employer.Id).WithAlias(() =>     peDTO.EmployerId))
       .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ProviderEmployerMapDTO>()).Future<ProviderEmployerMapDTO>();
```

Comment: great. just going to try this. be back in a minute.

Comment: can I just ask. In the second (employer) projection what would be the best way to approach the "where" clause. obviously i need to retrieve all employers associated to the provider I have just batched. but there is only a one way relationship between provider to employer. thanks

Comment: That's why I said the DTO might need to be modified. Can you place the ProviderId on the employer? Or is it a many to many? If it's many to many, you can write a projection of a list of ProviderId:EmployerId as a third future query (Add another DTO called ProviderEmployerDTO). Keep in mind that you want to use the same restrictions on all queries. ie: ProviderId == 1.

Comment: It is one to many. Ideally I would prefer not to have to add a provider reference to the employer. Is there any way to do the projection whilst I am still in the context of the first projection? thanks

Comment: maybe a sub select after the first projection? or something similar (not sure if this is possible!)

Comment: There isn't, because it's a sublist, at best you would cause duplicates. I see no reason why the DTO can't handle this for you, a DTO is really a throw away class used for transferring data, it shouldn't be used as a highlevel domain class. It's ideal that you modify it to handle this case. Or, you can create another DTO which just holds the relationships. Classes are cheap.

Comment: I don't mind the dto having extra references. I agree that is throw away. I just didn't want to add a provider reference to the employer domain model.

Comment: The only option then is to create a dto which holds the mapping ids.
I've updated the answer